# Can't get web browser to show on my phone page

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I'm very new at windows phone coding and I have what I think is a newbie problem :), my web browser doen't show. i first thought it was because i had said it to navigate at the constructor of my class, but changing it didn't solve anything.

Could anyone explain to me what's wrong?

Here is my code behind :

```cs
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        string site = "http://google.com/";

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);

        }


        private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            wB.Navigate(new Uri(site, UriKind.Absolute));
            wB.Navigating += new EventHandler<NavigatingEventArgs>(wB_Navigating);
        }

        void wB_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Uri);
            if (e.Uri.ToString() != (site))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("lalala");
               // NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Panorama.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Xaml :

```xml
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="LaBanquePostale.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <phone:WebBrowser Name="wB"  VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="Width"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top"/></Grid>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your WebBrowser and TextBlock are in the same Grid row.  It is possible that the TextBlock is hiding the WebBrowser, and that the WebBrowser has a height of `0` because it's verticalAlignment is set to Top.

Try removing the TextBlock and setting VerticalAlignment to Stretch, and see if that works.

Ultimately, your Grid should have two RowDefinitions, and look something like this:

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <RowDefinition Height="*" />
             <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <phone:WebBrowser Name="wB"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" d:LayoutOverrides="Width"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top"/></Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: ok, I still don't uderstant the way UI items works in WP7. but I'll look closer ! Thx guys

Comment: You'll find that many of them don't behave the way you expect them to.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be because you are setting VerticalAlignment="Top" against the WebBrowser control, removing this property setting, presents the WebBrowser control in my sample project.

Comment: dude you're awsome, that's the second time you helped me today, why does it do that ?

Comment: No problem, see the reasoning provided by Robaticus